# Make Java 1.7 default on the Centos server

Tags: java, linux, centos

I installed a new JRE 1.7 on my Centos server.

However, when I type in java -version it shows the version 1.6, which means the hosting provider preinstalled that before?

How do I shift it over to the new one 1.7 I installed and make it permanent?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install the JRE?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg Just downloaded the compressed binary and untarred it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `PATH` environment variable so that the `bin/` directory from your Java installation precedes the system-wide ones. For example, in my user-specific `~/.bashrc` configuration file for the Bash shell I currently have:

```
export PATH="/usr/java/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

Note that I *prepend* (rather than replace) the Java program path to the previous value of the `PATH` variable, so that other programs will keep working without requiring the use of absolute paths. As for `/usr/java/latest`, it is a symbolic link created by the RPM packages Oracle provides that points to the latest version of Oracle Java installed on my system.

Comment: This will only set it for the user...not system-wide; if you want it system-wide put a script in `/etc/profile.d`...

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg: assuming that the OP is using Bash, a line in `/etc/profile` would also help...

Answer (score 1):

For bash, edit the startup file (~/.bashrc):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:
export PATH
```

For sh, edit the profile file (~/.profile):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:
export PATH
```

Source: [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: I did that but then my other shell commands like ls and cat stopped working. Why is that?

Comment: It seems that the authors of the article have forgotten $PATH is the first line.